How to determine if PC is running Windows Home language localized?
I can read in an app we use to determine the user visible version fine, so that's not the issue. I know e.g. in French it's "Windows Famille".
Is there a list of what it's called in other languages?

Run winver and [edit] your question.  France isn't typically a region where Single Language is sold.

@Ramhound
We don't run the app, customers install and run it and we need to determine if it's Windows Home.  Also, France is monolingual as far as software.
And the question is about is there a list from, like y'know, Micsosoft or some other source that has this info.  Searching has not turned one up so hoping some that reads this, and gets it, might supply such information.

So you are asking for a list of what Windows Home Single Language is called in different languages? My suggestion is still run winver to determine which edition of Windows you are running. Windows Home Single Language is not typically sold outside of developing nations and Russia and China.

@Ramhound
That wasn't the question or issue.  It's our app, run by our customers.
What we need to determine we read from the registry already:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion then in the key EditionID you see e.g. 'Professional'.
The challenge, what this question was about, is that's there's no way we have found to distinguish "Home" editions of  Windows other than in English or French, which uses "Famille".
Is there a list of version names in each language - nothing found by us on Microsoft sites or elsewhere. Or another registry entry.

Sounds like a Stack Overflow question

@Ramhound
Here's the question in StackOverflow which never got resolved, same dilemma - only English.

If you ask for language version of the operating system installed then run the following cmd command: reg.exe query "HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\International" -v locale*. HTH.

@JosefZ  That was not at all the question.  It's about the Windows edition type, and these are text fields in the registry in the language of the version.
